# Identify differences (over-reporting and under-reporting) based on two columns in two pandas dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I would like to identify the rows that exist in one dataframe but not the other and the other way around. Both dataframes have two columns `id` and `sub_id` as the unique identifier.

Also, one caveat is that the sub_id `00` and `0` or `05` and `5` are technically the same and should be a match.

The first dataframe would look like such:

```
id     sub_id
G1     00
G1     F1
G2     N1
G3     W1
G3     00
G4     K5
```

And, the second dataframe would look like such:

```
id     sub_id
G1     00
G3     W1
G3     00
G4     K5
G4     00
G5     F1
```

I would like to find the records that exist in the first dataframe but not the second and write the string `under-reporting` for those records in a separate column. The result would look like this:

```
id     sub_id     Result
G1     00         
G1     F1         under-reporting
G2     N1         under-reporting
G3     W1
G3     00
G4     K5
```

On the other side, I would like to identify records in the second dataframe but not in the first dataframe and write the string "over-reporting". The result would look like such:

```
id     sub_id     Result
G1     00
G3     W1
G3     00
G4     K5
G4     00         over-reporting
G5     F1         over-reporting
```

Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try a [`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html#pandas-dataframe-merge) with indicator + [`map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html#pandas-series-map):

DF1 and Not DF2 (left merge):

```
merged = df1.merge(df2, how='left', on=['id', 'sub_id'], indicator='I')

merged['I'] = merged['I'].map({
    'both': np.nan,
    'left_only': 'under-reporting',
    'right_only': 'over-reporting'
})
```

`merged`:

```
   id sub_id                I
0  G1     00              NaN
1  G1     F1  under-reporting
2  G2     N1  under-reporting
3  G3     W1              NaN
4  G3     00              NaN
5  G4     K5              NaN
```

---

DF2 and not DF1 (right merge):

```
merged = df1.merge(df2, how='right', on=['id', 'sub_id'], indicator='I')

merged['I'] = merged['I'].map({
    'both': np.nan,
    'left_only': 'under-reporting',
    'right_only': 'over-reporting'
})
```

`merged`:

```
   id sub_id               I
0  G1     00             NaN
1  G3     W1             NaN
2  G3     00             NaN
3  G4     K5             NaN
4  G4     00  over-reporting
5  G5     F1  over-reporting
```

---

Both:

```
merged = df1.merge(df2, how='outer', on=['id', 'sub_id'], indicator='I')

merged['I'] = merged['I'].map({
    'both': np.nan,
    'left_only': 'under-reporting',
    'right_only': 'over-reporting'
})
print(merged)
```

`merged`:

```
   id sub_id                I
0  G1     00              NaN
1  G1     F1  under-reporting
2  G2     N1  under-reporting
3  G3     W1              NaN
4  G3     00              NaN
5  G4     K5              NaN
6  G4     00   over-reporting
7  G5     F1   over-reporting
```

---

To handle the caveat and ensure that all `sub_id` are two digits with leading zeros use [`zfill`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.zfill.html#pandas-series-str-zfill):

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({
    'id': ['G1', 'G1', 'G3'],
    'sub_id': [0, 'F1', 5]
})
#    id sub_id
# 0  G1      0
# 1  G1     F1
# 2  G3      5

df1['sub_id'] = df1['sub_id'].astype(str).str.zfill(2)
#    id sub_id
# 0  G1     00
# 1  G1     F1
# 2  G3     05
```

Comment: thank you so much for the solution. I just added one caveat, which is that the sub_id 00 and 0 or 05 and 5 are technically the same and should be a match. Is there anyway we could account for that trending 0 when using the merge function?

Comment: Just to clarify does this only apply to `00` type or all sub_ids that can be numbers should be numbers?

Comment: Only the sub_ids starting with the 0, because one dataset I am receiving will "trim" to ```0x``` to ```x```.

Comment: Okay, in that case, I'd recommend using `zfill` to put those 0s back. See the edit in the answer.

Comment: Thank you and ```zfill``` method makes sense. One additional question: why in the 'both' category, we did not choose to merge based on ids and subids? The code was ```merged = df1.merge(df2, how='outer', indicator='I')``` and there is not ```on=['id', 'sub_id']```

Comment: Since they're the only columns in both frames, and the merge condition is all columns, the `on` is optional for all of them. But if there are more columns than shown it is necessary to specify. Thanks for catching that; I've updated my answer.

Comment: sorry it might be a random question but before I applied the left merge method, I have 1824 records in ```df1```. For some reasons after the left merge, I have 1830 records in the ```merged```. And I just checked there is no duplicate for when using id and sub_ids.

Comment: actually I just checked there are exactly 6 duplicates in ```df2```. Is there anyway we could left merge considering the duplicates but without actually dropping the duplicates?

Comment: Since, we've already reached the comment length limit on this answer. I'd recommend making a new question with a small sample frame  with duplicates in DF2 and outline how you'd like them to be handled. You can link to this question and answer to help give whoever solves that problem a headstart, also to prevent the new question from being marked a duplicate of this one.

Comment: no worries at all! I used the method in this thread and and was able to merge considering dups. Thanks again!